# What's the single-word for "left or right handed"?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

'Male'/'female' is to 'gender' as 'left-handed'/'right-handed 'is to...?

Is there a word to describe this? For example, if I ask a guy

> What's your ____?

It should mean I'm asking whether he's left or right-handed.

Another example could be

> Our designs are not biased  against your ____.

Basically, I'm looking for something that means the state of being left- or right-handed which could be used analogously as gender.

**EDIT:** Sorry for the delay in the edit, but I was tied up. There are some points I'd like to clarify:

1. I'm not looking for a way to paraphrase my questions. I'm looking for a single word. I know people normally ask something along the lines of "*Are you left-handed or not?*" People also ask "*Are you afraid of the dark?*" instead of "*Are you scotophobiac?*". The word for it, [along with 3 others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_the_dark) still exists, right?
2. It has been pointed out that I should go with `Our designs are not biased against left-handed people` as that is what I mean. But that is not necessarily what I mean.

For example, let's say there is a washbasin with the tap on the right. Clearly, it's biased against lefties. Sometimes, you come across a washbasin with a tap on the left. (The logic being: you use your left hand to turn the tap as your right one's dirty). But, your right hand might not always be dirty, in which case, it's biased against righties.

A washbasin with the tap on the center is, then, handedness-blind or chirality-blind, if you will. (I foresee that some would dwell on `Our designs are symmetrical`. Please don't.)

I'm looking for a term that would be applicable here, as well as in the 1st example.

My favorite so far is **chirality**, suggested by Dan Bron in a comment (with 25 upvotes!) But, I'm reluctant to use it because there's no hard proof it's used in that sense

If we are talking about male-female, gender works perfectly. `What's your gender?` and `Our designs aren't biased against your gender.` , both work perfectly here.

Sorry for the late edit again. If the consensus is that I rollback, I will. Let me know in the comments.

Comment: If you want to be an unpopular pedant, I offer you *chirality*.

Comment: @DanBron do you have a reference for *chirality* that supports it's use for people?  I'm only familiar with *chiral* ***structures*** (e.g. molecules) and a quick check supports this.

Comment: Note that designs may be described as *ambidextrous* (e.g.. computer mice).

Comment: @DanBron: What Chris said.

Comment: @ChrisH: ambidextrous might be unambiguous, but what I need would be dexterity, which isn't.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Hey, if you guys don't like *chirality*, try out Mari-Lou's *laterality* (the common and idiomatic answer is, of course, Chris' *handedness*, but if you use that, you won't earn your pedant merit badge).

Comment: @DanBron: I don't mind sounding pedantic, as long as there's proof I'm not talking about [chemistry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chiral?q=chirality#chiral__5).

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Epistemologically speaking, I am incapable of offering proof; the most I can ever offer is [evidence](https://bonald.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/of-course-liberals-are-smarter-than-conservatives/).

Comment: @DanBron: I'm convinced. But if I use it, I'm not sure my audience will be.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Secretly, I'm not either. That's why I offered it as a comment rather than an answer. I don't want to build a track record of unsubstantiated opinion.

Comment: @DanBron: I'll take my turn as the pedant. It's actually not a matter of whether we're talking about molecules or not. *Chirality* isn't just a fancy name for *handedness* in the sense that most of us mean when we talk about handedness. Yes, *chirality* shows up in dictionaries as **a** sense of handedness. But what it really means is that you have a distinguishable left and right. It doesn't mean one is dominant. There is no such thing as "left chirality". You are chiral or you're not. You have chirality or you don't.

Comment: I'd rather say "Our product works equally work for left- and right-handed users.".

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Everyone would rather say that. That's why I'm looking for a single word. The sheer absence of the term itself is proof of the bias I'm looking to describe.

Comment: All the answers so far would confuse me. Everyone I've ever known has asked either *are you right- or left-handed?* or *which is your dominant hand?*

Comment: @JohnY Usage in literature does not support that position; see for example [*Progress in Biological Chirality*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MwazbzMkzg8C&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=%22left+chirality%22&source=bl&ots=fgKG4lmiV-&sig=pzyZHrJuic7mOlXUT05wRjMFa7M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5vw7VcqcL4SbNty9gMgP&ved=0CCkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22left%20chirality%22&f=false) or [*Chirality in the Neutrino*](http://lappweb.in2p3.fr/neutrinos/achiralite.html) or any of the other results when you search Google for "left chirality" (with quotes).

Comment: @DanBron: Huh. Well, OK then. I guess I'll have to settle for being the *overly* pedantic type, analogous to the "pedants" who insist that it's incorrect to end a sentence with a preposition, etc.

Comment: @JohnY You mean you're < *beat* > hypercorrect? (I've got a million of them, folks!)

Comment: In your specific case, why don't you just say "Our product does not bias against left-handedness"?  Since Left-handedness is the less common thing to be, and the thing that would most likely be biased against, it says exactly what you want to say without any confusion at all.

Comment: _Dextrocity_, anyone?  Or does that make it sound too atrocious? :-)

Comment: Ooh, you cannot make such a significant edit like that, and so late in the day too. Not after all these votes and views. In one clarificatory edit you have *possibly* nullified six answers. (Mine's still valid though!) But seeing as the top two answers are not terribly affected, you might get away it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I know, I'm sorry. I was away for a while, unable to edit, but I knew I had to edit after reading tchrist's answer. (I commented I would). Frankly, I never expected this to get 5k views in 2 days!

Comment: If it's any comfort, I think the edit has made the question more valid and pertinent (i.e. It's a better question). But I could be biased...

Comment: All the uses I've seen of _chirality_ seem to refer to some kind of physical structure, even in the case of left-handed or right-handed subatomic particles. They also imply that you can only be one way or the other; there is no "ambidextrous" chirality, whereas some humans may work equally well with left or right hands. I would say if you know two people, one of whom has only the right arm and one of whom has only the left arm, they are of different chirality. But most people are considered bilaterally symmetric in regard to their hands.

Comment: @pacerier the OP never mentioned 'handedness'  in his question. Hence Chris's answer  is the most upvoted. Now it looks as if he ignored the OP completely.

Comment: The OP didn't even know that "handedness" was a proper word! And now it's in the title??!

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/287031/8278

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another option would be ***hand-dominance*** or ***hand-dominancy*** as a single word. It is not as common as *handedness* and I usually see it in medical contexts. (It is usually in two words but you can hyphenate to form a hyphenated compound noun).

> Research shows that hand dominancy can be an important feature affecting one's tolerance of pain. According to a 2009 Israeli study from the University of Haifa, right-handed people are more tolerant of pain than left-handed individuals.
>
> <sub>*Understanding Pain: An Introduction for Patients and Caregivers* By Naheed Ali, Moshe Lewis</sub>

It might encompass the *left-hand-dominance* and *right-hand-dominance* better than *handedness*. *Handedness* can be better understood as a broader term that covers *mixed-handedness* and *ambidexterity* also.

They are mentioned as synonyms in some contexts but here is an explanation of the differences between *hand dominance, handedness* and *hand preference*:

> Hand dominance means that one hand has the most influence or control. Handedness means that one hand is more reliable for use across a range of skillful acts. Hand preference means that one hand is preferred or chosen.
>
> <sub>[www.erhardtproducts.com](http://www.erhardtproducts.com/faq_handpref.html)</sub>

Additionally, there are *eye-dominance* and *ear-dominance*; and there is the hypernym *side-dominance* that covers all different types of dominance.

Comment: _Our designs are not biased against your hand-dominance_. Sounds right to me. As does _What's your hand-dominance_. Thanks. This answer, though not ideal, is as close as it gets for my purposes

Comment: I think this sounds even better as _dominant hand_ (although I understand that's two words, instead of the desired singleton). _Our designs are not biased against your dominant hand._

Comment: @J.R.: Yes, you are right. It is a more natural way to say it and it was already mentioned before. However, I gave this answer after OP indicated that he doesn't prefer other answers and after his update.

Answer (score 181):

I don't think you'll improve on **handedness** [(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handedness) [(reference.com)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/handedness).  It's not a very nice word admittedly, and sounds a bit like what you started with, but there aren't any synonyms listed in this sense.

Comment: *Handedness* is the right word, and I think it doesn’t sound bad at all. It’s often used in a technical sense, as in the handedness of a coordinate system.

Comment: @JonPurdy, in that sense I'm familiar enough with it that it is just part of the language -- it's when referring to people that I have something unspecified against it.

Comment: Our designs do not bias against _handedness_? Does that sound right?

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction: It sounds absolutely right to me, because it's the right answer. It really is the word you are looking for.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction, yes -- I must just have something against it.

Comment: @ Sounds wrong to me, just like "bias against gender" sounds wrong. If you want to use handedness, you could say something "Our product works equally well regardless of your handedness.".

Comment: @JonPurdy I think it must be a typical society's thing, that people tend to call things "un-English" that are technical terms some of which are only used in special domains. IIRC, in the pre-CS and pre-computer era, the singular _parent_ was mainly known by biologists and zoologists, for instance (as well as mathematicians conceiving special  algorithms)

Comment: @CodesInChaos I like it better if you remove the "your", _Our product works equally well regardless of handedness._

Comment: @slicedtoad It sounds better, but I think it's more difficult to understand.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yeah, I think I just prefer: _Our product is completely ambidextrous._ Doesn't directly answer the question but it's a much better sentence.

Comment: The tendency of English speakers to expect a single word for a given context is not necessarily reasonable. In many contexts a phrase would be clearer to explain your meaning; `handedness` is about has close as you'll get for wide understanding, unless you're only targeting a technical or academic audience.

Comment: Though `handedness` is the unambiguously correct single-word answer here, in re. the original question, it's never really idiomatic to ask it in the form of "What's your handedness?", at least not anywhere I've experienced. "Are you left- or right-handed?" is pretty much the form that question always takes.

Comment: @slicedtoad, I contend that ambidexterity is the ability to use a/both hands, and therefore cannot apply to a product that is to be used. This fits with how the word dexterity is used. If something is difficult to handle, it "requires dexterity".

Comment: @boileau historically and etymologically that may be true, but in terms of current usage it's not -- I'm currently using a [Logitech G300 'ambidextrous' mouse](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-au/product/g300-optical-gaming-mouse).  Elsewhere it's described as symmetrical, which is also true.  I chose it because I'm -- here's a nice neologism for you -- [ambimousetrous](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ambimousetrous).

Comment: @boileau An ambidextrous _person_ is capable of using either hand. When you call an object ambidextrous, it's not much of a stretch to understand that it can _be used_ by either hand. And as Chris commented, it's used this way all the time.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction: you subtly changed the phrase for your comment. "Not biased against handedness" sounds wrong, because there was never any question of bias against the very concept of handedness. "Not biased against your handedness" is fine. It means whatever handedness you have (and let's not commit a false dichotomy here, the reader may be left-, right-, ambi-, trans-, bi-curious or undecided), we're not biased against that handedness.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'd edit the comment if I could. It was made before I edited the question to include 'your', as its absence was deemed erroneous by some. If it's any consolation," Our designs do not bias against your handedness" sounds equally awkward to me.

Comment: @ChrisH I checked the dictionary definitions and did a cursory check for ambidextrous products before commenting, but I see I overlooked the many examples of ambidextrous mice. It still sounds to me like wrongly implying that an item has dexterity, though.

Answer (score 66):

Handedness is the most common and most understandable term. But I'm going for my pedant merit badge, so I'm going to draw upon and explain the other suggestions.

### A history and evolution of meaning: Chiral

@DanBron suggests the technical term [Chirality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality):

> The word chirality is derived from the Greek, χειρ (kheir), "hand", a familiar chiral object.
>
> An object or a system is chiral if it is distinguishable from its mirror image; that is, it cannot be superposed onto it.

There has been a great degree of speculation as to whether chirality is applicable to the specific *chiral* orientation or if it is merely the property of being non-superposable. To clear it up, consider the following definitions.

> **chiral**
> adjective, Chemistry
> **1.** (of a molecule) not superimposable on its mirror image.
>
> <sub>chirality. (n.d.). Collins English Dictionary - Complete & Unabridged 10th Edition. Retrieved April 28, 2015, from Dictionary.com website: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chirality</sub>

Chiral is the adjectival property of whether an object possesses symmetry, dissymmetry; whether it is superimposable or it is achiral/amphichiral. These have the same definition: not chiral; lacking any chirality in the same way that asexual means non-gendered; neither male nor female. In chemistry, pairs of molecules with opposite chirality are called [enantiomer's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enantiomer), sometimes optical isomers; in mathematics enantiomorphs is more common.

> **chirality**
> noun
> **1.** the configuration or handedness (left or right) of an asymmetric, optically active chemical compound. Also called *dissymmetry*
>
> <sub>chirality. (n.d.). Collins English Dictionary - Complete & Unabridged 10th Edition. Retrieved April 28, 2015, from Dictionary.com website: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chirality</sub>

Chiral is a quite new addition to the English language, having only been though up by Lord Kelvin in 1893. The definitions for the word in technical fields *and* common language are evolving, but the suffix -ity is winning out for the meaning of chirality.

> Used to form a noun from an adjective; especially, to form the noun referring to the state, property, or quality of conforming to the adjective's description.

### Handedness vs. Chiral

Handedness is commonly used to distinguish between the distinct items of a chiral pair – indeed, almost every definition or explanation of chirality I've heard (or Google suggested just now) uses the mirror symmetry of human hands as a prime example. For instance in [physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)), for subatomic particles that have a spin, one will be referred to as having left-handed spin, the other as having right-handed spin. It's also applied to describe helix structures (DNA/RNA and threaded screws), [electromagnetic and other vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) where the right-hand-rule is well known, knots and several other geometric and mathematical notions.

JasonC suggests that handedness is a behavioral preference and therefore chirality is not an applicable synonym. However, manual dexterity is as least much a matter of skill as preference. Becoming a switch hitter in baseball requires a great deal of work. Many highly trained and motivated professional athletes do not succeed at overcoming this behavioral preference even though it provides a noticeable advantage to their career. People tend to see their hand dominance (or preference) as a part of themselves, a defining characteristic. In that sense, handedness is as much a physical configuration as a behavioral one.

Chirality is technically correct when applied to people's hands, but almost never used. (That's part of why I like it; [it's the best kind of correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bsQl.gif).) However, in American English, it's not the right way to ask a person about themselves, mostly because it doesn't communicate the question as several commenters have pointed out. Communication will fail at a rate inversely proportional to the renown of the words (and grammar) used; the words chiral and chirality are not well known by many people without specialized knowledge of science, technology, engineering or math, **so don't use chirality.** It is not used and will not be understood in common language. If you're pitching a design for a [nightlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightlight) (or even a horror movie), you can't just say "Are you scotophobic, nyctophobic, lygophobic or achluophobic? Then you'll love this!"

I'm basing my suggestion against chirality and the rest of this answer on the assumption that anyone talking about their designs is seeking to communicate with a broad audience. In short, you question sounds like you're trying to market your designs and marketing messages that are not understood often achieve the opposite of the desired effect. You will drive your clientele away if they don't understand you with minimal effort. If you are specifically trying to be coy and pique their interest by challenging their assumptions, I still suggest you stay away from uncommon technical terms. Unless you are speaking directly and exclusively to an audience you have every reason to expect will know the term chirality, I suggest you don't use it.

Furthermore, chirality might be assumed by people who know the greek root to referred to hand preference. Or a listener might assume you're asking about their hand preference because our left and right hands are the most ubiquitous identifiers of our asymmetry. But technically speaking, chirality could refer to any aspect of human asymmetry, of which there are many: wrists, elbows, shoulders, legs, feet, kidneys, ears etc. etc. all cannot be superimposed on their mirrored pair in the body.

- I lost a foot to a tractor accident.
- My left nostril is slightly larger.
- Every body part I have two of.

Are all correct and applicable answers to the question "What is your chirality?"

But even replacing it with the strict synonym 'handedness' can be confusing.

### Eliciting a left-or-right response

I think your first example is best filled by using two words (and to hell with the single-word-request tag). I think it's far more common and understandable to ask:

> What's your **dominant hand**?

This makes it most clear that you're interested in an either-or, left-or-right answer. As some commenters point out, handedness is a spectrum; some people may write with one hand and eat, brush their teeth, cut their food etc. with the other. Nonetheless, when asked directly about which hand is dominant, most people will correctly identify that it's left or right, map it to whatever activities they consider most important, and answer 'left' or 'right'.

<sub>I'm basing this on the asker's mention of "state of being left- or right-handed" indicating the desire for an either-or, binary answer. If you want a nuanced answer on a spectrum, use the more open ended "handedness" option.</sub>

### Inclusive instead of Exclusive language

Similarly, I think it would be very weird to hear:

> Our designs do not bias against gender. Our designs are a-gendered/gender neutral.
>
> Our designs do not bias against handedness. (Or, for that matter...)
>
> Our designs do not bias against chirality. Our designs are achiral/chiral neutral.

The distinction itself - gender or handedness - isn't what you'd be biased towards or against. That phrasing implies your designs are for suitable for both gendered and asexual people (or handed and ambidextrous people). I think what you're trying to convey is that your designs are suitable for all people, whether they left-handed, right-handed or ambidextrous. Therefore, I humbly suggest (or rather second Chris H.'s suggestion):

> Our designs are ambidextrous.

The prefix ambi- is inclusive, meaning [both](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambi), unlike a prefix of un- or a- which would mean neither. Saying a person is ambidextrous means they use both hands equally well. Saying an inanimate object or design is ambidextrous implies that people can use either hand to hold, use or operate it equally well. A steering wheel is ambidextrous - it would be hard to imagine one that wasn't (because circles lack chirality). A gear shifter is typically right-handed in cars with a left-handed driver seat (and vice-versa in Britain, e.g.).

And if you're talking about an animate object, ambidextrous is the only way to go!

> Our robot designs are ambidextrous.

As you correctly point out, however, you can't remove the prefix from ambidextrous and make any kind of sense. Dexterity by itself doesn't describe handedness or chirality. If you ask someone about their dexterity, you'd get a wide variety of interpretations - my grandmother would start talking about knitting and I'd [roll three six-sided dice](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Dexterity).

Sliding back into the marketing angle, promoting your product or design as not biased is taking a defensive tone. It is building a subtle connection in the listeners mind between your product and bias. I suggest you try very hard to find a positive or neutral way to describe your designs.

> A washbasin with the tap on the center is, then, handedness-blind or chirality-blind, if you will.

It's also precisely ambidextrous.

> ambidextrous
> adjective
> 1.1 (Of an implement) designed to be used by left-handed and right-handed people with equal ease:
>
> <sub>ambidextrous. (n.d.). In *Oxford Dictionaries*. Retrieved April 29, 2015, from http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ambidextrous</sub>

Comment: It's "technically correct" when applied to people, but not in the way you seem to think it is. Someone who is left-handed has exactly the same *chirality* as someone who is right-handed, or someone who is ambidextrous. It's a property that you have or you don't, and every human has it.

Comment: I do agree that *ambidextrous* is a nice option, though, if rephrasing the sentence is an option.

Comment: "A pedant would never misspell *pedant*!" I'm not yet a certified pedant, thus the need to earn my badge :-D @JohnY Regarding chirality, I disagree. Chiral is the adjective of possessing chirality; it's antonym is " non-chiral object is called achiral (sometimes also amphichiral) and can be superposed on its mirror image."(Wikipedia). Chirality is not a synonym of chiral. [Chirality](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chirality) is a noun; it is the specific property of chiral orientation. So, about that badge...

Comment: @PatrickM: Well, my understanding *had been* that *chirality* meant "the property of being chiral". Meaning, if a thing can be superimposed on its mirror image, then it is not chiral, and thus does not have chirality. I have to say my understanding is evolving. But I will note that left-handed, right-handed, and ambidextrous humans all *do* have the same chirality, in both the sense that I meant and the sense implied by sumelic.

Comment: "Six sided dice" is pretty much the default. You and I know what 3d6 means, but I'm pretty sure that you could mention three dice rolls without anyone questioning how many sides each die has!

Comment: "Chirality is technically correct when applied to people, but almost never used." - [But can be great when it is](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0797694/)

Comment: If you said "chirality", most people wouldn't know what you meant, and most of those that did would probably have to spend some time trying to decipher it first, ultimately understanding but wondering why you didn't just say "handedness". I'm not really sure it's a choice worth considering. Most thesauruses don't even have an entry for "handedness", and those that do only have "laterality", never "chirality". As interesting a word as it may be, the benefit of being a bit creative probably isn't worth the cost of nobody understanding you (thus defeating the purpose of communicating).

Comment: @JasonC It's not 'creative', it's a word in the English language. I don't care what thesauruses say, I care about the exact definition of the word and the applicability to the askers situation. Based on that applicability alone, I agree that its not the right choice. Neither is handedness, in my opinion. My strict suggestion is that "What is your dominant hand?" is the clearest, most neutral and accurate way to ask the question. I explain why in the 2nd half of the answer.

Comment: @PatrickM  The "exact definition" of the word concerns the physical appearance of an object, which has zero relevance to handedness. So going by that, it is *definitely* the wrong word. You stretching it to somehow also cover behavioral preferences *is* creative, and if nobody understands what you've meant, then it is a failure of communication as well. The suggestion to use the word "chirality" is terrible indeed, and a claim of caring about "exact definitions" hurts the case even more, as the exact definition bears no relevance to the question asked. No dictionary supports your claim.

Comment: This is begging for a TL;DR

Comment: A duck's reproductive apparatus is chiral. One curls clockwise, the other counter-clockwise. Humans are not, for the most part, chiral. I am with Jason C on this, it is a very bad choice of a word for handedness.

Answer (score 16):

I suggest **[laterality](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/laterality)**.
I think this works, it's less obscure than *chirality*; and  readers should find the term, *laterality*, self-explanatory if used in the proper context.

> *noun*;  1640-1650
>
> 1. the use of one hand in preference to the other.
>      Compare *handedness*.
>
> *laterality* in Medicine
>   **laterality** lat·er·al·i·ty (lāt'ə-rāl'ĭ-tē)
>   *n.* Preferential use of limbs of one side of the body.
>
> 2. the dominance or superior development of one side of the body or brain.

Examples of *laterality* used in literature

- Humans are bilateral animals; accordingly, [laterality is the dominance, or preference of, one side of the body or brain](http://listverse.com/2010/11/25/10-examples-of-human-laterality/), such as the hand or foot (sides usually being left or right).
- There is no extensive agreement on the origin of manual preferences. Some believe [such laterality is inherited](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/331534/laterality); others, that the child is trained to it; and still others, that biases are initiated in an infant during pregnancy
- Laterality refers to an important change in the brain that permits an [‘internal awareness of the two sides of the body and their differences’](http://www.theimportanceofbeing0to5years.com/moving-moments/laterality-does-my-left-brain-know-what-my-right-hand-is-doing/) (Newel Kephart) [...] Until a child is about 3 years of age both sides of the brain perform the same types of functions. [...] The two hemispheres of the brain are still doing the same things in the same way. If your child has had plenty of sensory and motor experiences as an infant and toddler, the brain matures and certain functions are specialised in one hemisphere or side of the brain – this is the process of *lateralisation* (the word lateralisation’ comes from the Latin word meaning ‘side’).
- Other [existing asymmetries or lateralities](https://www.google.it/search?q=hand%20laterality&oq=laterality%20hand&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.11140j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=leg%20laterality) in humans, such as arm folding, hand clasping, and leg crossing, have been ...

---

There are two advantages to preferring **laterality** which the term *handedness* does not offer. It is a more rigorous expression. And it fits perfectly in the following statement—

> Our designs are not biased against your laterality.

Comment: "Whose side are you on, anyway?" <silence> "Hey! I asked you, WHAT'S YOUR LATERALITY?!"

Comment: _it's self-explanatory_. Is it, though? Not to knock your answer, but I've never heard it used in that sense.

Comment: It's not self-explanatory to me (native British English speaker). It would make me stop and think "What word does this person using EFL really mean?". Or more whimsically, "OK , so the opposite of laterality is presumably formerality, but I don't quite get the pun on "literal" or "later" and "formal" here ... or was the question about about left-wing and right-wing politics? *Chirality* is the right word, but it's not common enough to really answer the OP's question.  You would normally just ask "are you right or left handed?"

Comment: Lateral thinking? Brain hemispheres... [**lateral**: early 15c., from Middle French *latéral* and directly from Latin *lateralis* “belonging to the side”](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Lateral&searchmode=none) Your average Romance speaker will understand the term IMO.

Comment: This is the word I came up with too. It's exactly correct. However, it suffers from being obscure; not everyone would understand it.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer so far, followed maybe by handedness. I have only seen chirality used when refering to molecular structures. +1.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Lateral thinking" is used so often with brain teasers that I'd expect people to think it means "thinking outside the box", having nothing to do with sided-ness.  Like Area51 and alephzero, I doubt I would've figured out what _laterality_ means

Comment: @Izkata Possibly, the two expressions tend to go hand in hand :) But if the term laterality is used in context, it shouldn't cause any problems. Isolated, I agree, it might cause a few to scratch their heads. It fits nicely in the title though.

Comment: Fwiw: http://bit.ly/1DRFbY6 ; also, +1 for this being pretty much the only synonym actually listed in thesauruses for "handedness" (in those that actually list any synonyms).

Comment: "Laterality" does seem a superior choice to "chirality" based on the latter being tied more to chemistry and the like.  However, even knowing what lateral means, I find the meaning of laterality unintuitive; it seems it should roughly mean an orientation such as "the laterality of the line was orthogonal to Z".  If you asked what my laterality was, I'd have no idea, and might think you were picking a fight. The word is not at all self-explanatory.

Comment: But, is the whole terminology really self-explanatory? Even simple terms like "male/female" _sound_ unrelated to "gender" or "sex". I bet that it's inobvious for young kids that are just about to learn english. But who would try to use something like "maleness" here, hm? Personally, at first I was trying to use simple word formation and (really) I ended up using the "handness". But it always sounded odd to me. What is your handness? How are you handed? uh, this just sounds wrong to me. Once presented with "lateralization"(?) or "laterality", it sounded much better, although not really related.

Answer (score 11):

I cannot quite tell why you want to know this, but I strongly advise rewording.

You seem to think everybody is one thing or the other, while in fact this has no basis in biology; most people’s [handedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handedness) exists on a continuum, just as they do with so many other factors, including footedness and eyedness and a whole lot more. Although I am not one of them, I know lots of people whose handedness, footedness, and eyedness are not all three of them the same sort of lateral dominance. For example, they might be left-handed and -footed but right-eyed.

However, if you just want clumping not nuance, you should ask exactly what you mean and not use fancy words or beat around the bush:

1. Are you left-handed?

If you want nuance, then ask about each aspect:

2. What hand do you usually write with?
3. What hand do you usually eat with?
4. What hand do you usually throw with?
5. What hand do you usually catch with?

What is your purpose?  I feel like you’re trying to squeeze something into a slot that English doesn’t put there. If you what to know whether someone is right- or left-handed, for goodness’ sake just ask them that! You are making a mistake by trying to formulate a complete sentence and then seeking a single word that fits in that slot. So your sample:

> What’s your ____?

Is a problem because that isn’t what people ask. They ask:

- Are you right-handed or left-handed?

Now and then they might ask:

- Which hand do you use?

Sure, you could ask

- What’s your dominant hand?

But that’s a pretty specialized and clinical use.  The same goes [with eyes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocular_dominance) and feet, where just like hands, a person tends to be dominant in one but not the other. The right question then is:

- Are you left-eyed?

or even

- Are you left- or right-eye dominant?

Even so, that sounds intrusive.  For the most part, this is just not a question that gets asked, and if it is, one asks in the normal way, not in a way that reaches for some abstruse term nobody ever uses. That’s completely counterproductive.

[Same with feet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footedness).  Asking

- What’s your dominant foot?

Just sounds funny, and people do not usually talk that way.

You have the same problem with saying:

> Our designs are not biased against your ____.

While it is *possible* to say

- Our designs are not biased against your **manual orientation**.

You are apt to confuse all but the quick-witted, again because people really don’t talk about these things this way in English.

I suppose you could say

- Our designs are not biased against left-handers.

Which is what you really mean, but it comes off sounding more than a little sinister, so I wouldn’t trust that not to bother someone or other. Then again, so does everything.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a good reason for asking. And I intend to edit my question to include it as soon as I get the chance. (I'll be traveling for a few days and I can't make long posts on my phone). Long story short, I want it to distinguish things designed for righties (scissors) from things that aren't (spoons). A majority of things are. And it ticks me off that I don't even know the word for it. Or worse, that there no such word. I'm a lefty, BTW.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Hand only, or also foot and eye?

Comment: If you're asking about me, then yes, I do put my left foot first in a pair of pants.

Comment: @Area51Detective I asked because I wondered whether you had the whole trifecta. I figured you were a lefty because nobody in any 90% group ever thinks about people not like them.  I can think of a zillion examples and I'm sure you can too. And yes, I have the trifecta.

Comment: You may want to add a note that "handedness" itself need not be uniform or "dominant" across all activities: Some tennis players (most famously, Rafael Nadal!) play tennis left-handed but use their right hand for writing; some write with their right hand but use their left hand for cutting with scissors; etc.

Comment: This post doesn't really offer *any* solution, instead it offers a whole variety of different approaches, and at the same time, says neither one is perfectly suitable. :)

Answer (score 8):

In relation to firearms that are designed to operate indifferent of left/right handed use, the description is always "ambidextrous design" implying designed for use with **EITHER** hand, instead of saying "designed for ambidextrous use" which could entail requires both hands (ie handlebars)

Comment: Hello Charles. _Ambidextrous_ would be an answer to 'Male'/'female' is to 'hermaphrodite' as 'left-handed'/'right-handed 'is to…?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I mistakenly thought the OP was asking in regard to the appropriate method for advertising a product that is designed indifferent to which hand it is used with.

Comment: I'm glad you agree. I don't like to argue with people who can shoot with either hand.

Comment: I typically encounter that term with computer mice. Interesting that you went with firearms instead...

Comment: Thanks for answering. I wasn't aware of 'ambidextrous' being used in this way. Upvote. But you're right about being mistaken. I'm looking for a term that fits _do not bias against ...._. But thanks for showing a way to paraphrase this.

Answer (score 6):

The most fun answer is: [**sinisterness**<sup>Ref</sup>](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sinister).
From the Latin, it literally means "Left Handed"-ness.

Appropriately enough, [usage grew with the run-up to WWII and the Cold War](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sinisterness&case_insensitive=on&year_start=900&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3):

[image: Sinisterness usage]

Comment: Damn eastern lefty chiralistic anti-rightists...

Comment: I'd wager the majority of those uses are in the sense of how sinister ("threatening or portending evil, harm, or trouble; ominous") something is, not how left-handed it is

Comment: @user568458, maybe so.  But as the ancients knew, and by the Latin word definition, left-handed and many of those adjectives you listed, are one and the same. (^_^)

Comment: Such an astonishing term! At first I was suprised, but then, I remembered *righteous* and now I see the trace of the process that formed both of them. Left-side was often a synonym for bad, wrong or evil.. Sinistra/destra = left/right in Italian (close to Latin).. ->[How did sinister the latin word for left handed get its current meaning](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39092/how-did-sinister-the-latin-word-for-left-handed-get-its-current-meaning) What a beautifuly naturally-misunderstadable term! Pure evil! So pretty!

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something that sounds a little more scientific/technical (though they would not be as immediately understood as **handedness**, nor as technical as **chirality**), you could use something in between like:

> [**manual bias**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/manual)
>
> or
>
> [**dextral bias**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinistral_and_dextral)

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example, there's a much easier way to phrase what you want to say.

"Our product does not bias against **Left-handedness**."

Since left-handedness is the less common state of being, it is the more likely state to be biased against - and by clarifying that your product is not biased against left-handedness, you clarify that it does not discriminate in the expected way.

It doesn't specify that it also does not bias against right-handedness, but because right-handedness is more common, it's not assumed that it will be biased against, and therefore does not have to be explicitly stated.  While there are some rare cases where there *is* bias against right-handedness, such as left-handed scissors, this isn't explicit in non-bias towards left-handedness.

Comment: Left-handed scissors are biased against right-handed people; your phrasing would be "correct" for them but for the wrong reason.

Comment: @Wooble Noted.  I still believe there wouldn't be very many cases for confusion, and that it isn't explicitly biased against right-handedness for not being biased against left-handedness.

Comment: I also feel it's a bit like the phrase "reverse discrimination". It sort of suggests there's a correct thing to be biased against, and that it should be notable you're not being biased against it.

Comment: @Wooble While ideally nothing would be biased against anything, in this case it is a design principle that causes the bias.  While it's not an ideal situation, it is an honest explanation of how things are.

Answer (score 0):

Could it not be described as dexterity?

> dex·ter·i·ty
>
> noun
>
> skill in performing tasks, especially
> with the hands.

Ref. [Google - Define dexterity](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+dexterity&oq=define+dexterity&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4015j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Welcome to the ELU. Can you please edit to provide a reference for the definition, as suggested by the [help centre instructions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)  :-)

Comment: "Our designs are not biased against your dexterity" sounds more like "Our designs are not biased against your level of skill in performing tasks with the hands", i.e.  designs that are usable by clumsy people or people with manual disabilities such as arthritis

Answer (score -1):

**The Single Word**

I completely agree with [many others](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/241618/70061) that **handedness** is the word you're looking for here, if you're looking for a single word.

**Phrasing**

However, I think your phrasing sounds awkward. Rather than

> Our designs are not biased against your gender

I would expect

> Our designs are not gender-biased

Similarly, rather than

> Our designs are not biased against your handedness

I would expect

> Our designs are not handedness-biased

**Positive Statements**

However, you generally want to make positive statements about your products, rather than negative ones, so it would probably be better to say

> Our designs are gender-neutral

or

> Our designs are handedness-neutral

But, I agree with [Charles Watson](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/241681/70061) that **ambidextrous** is the appropriate way to describe a product that ignores handedness, so I would say

> Our designs are ambidextrous

Answer (score -2):

I like "laterality".  In psychology there's a thing called bilateral transfer, which is where practicing a task with one hand produces a (usually smaller) improvement when using the other.

Comment: laterality [has already been suggested](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/241649/106801).

Answer (score -2):

I submit dextriosity or dextrosity.  Most people are familiar with the term ambidextrious, so it's a logical derivation, and this is the way new words are created - through common usage and general understanding.  Handedness can work, though many people seem to agree that it feels clumsy; hence the search for a new word.   Let the pedants weigh in!

Comment: @erich the OP *says* that these words are neologisms.He's *submitting* them.

Comment: i'm not sure a neologism is necessary; you may be thinking of **dexterity**, but this has already been [suggested](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/241964/106801).