# Word meaning: "The act of taking/obtaining that of which is rightly yours, but you've never had."

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, verbs

Other examples include:
"Liberating oneself by obtaining a right or value one deserves, but has never had."
"To have the ability to do something for the first time."

Something like *secure, capture, or seize,* except case specific and all encompassing.

Is there a word for this? Thanks!

Comment: To ***claim***.

Comment: In my opinion, @DanBron has nailed it... I think that should be the answer (+1). claim: 'to demand as being due or as one's property; assert one's title or right to'

Comment: @SamuelVimes Feel free to post it as an answer w/ that definition. I'm on the road and don't have access to a computer.

Comment: @DanBrown Thank you very much for your offer =), however the merit is yours and it would not feel right answering it in your place...

Comment: @ermanen yet another meaning of claim is also "to take". For example: "Every time we return to real time, Death is waiting to claim those who have cheated him." ( Jennifer Fallon TREASON KEEP (2001) )

Comment: @ermanen The heirs of an exiled king are often described as returning to their homeland to *claim the throne*.  The words *redeem* (as in coupon) and *reclaim* would also work.

Comment: A phrase which pretty much encompasses the whole meaning is to "claim your birthright".

Comment: I guess **stealing** doesn't work, since it's a `right or value one deserves`?

Comment: @DanBron   Along with [*chirality*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241616/male-female-is-to-gender-as-left-handed-right-handed-is-to/241661#comment521662_241616), you have a habit of giving very good answers to questions that are NOT off topic. Tsk...tsk.... People just don't like claiming credit to answers that have been left as comments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I know, I've been feeling guilty about that lately. The problem is 98% of the time I'm visiting EL&U on my phone, so it's difficult-to-impossible to post a proper answer, especially a well-formatted and more importantly *substantiated* one. I find when I start composing an answer in the mobile app, then go to Safari to research it a little and collect citations, by the time I'm back, the answer I'm composing has timed-out and I've lost everything I've written :(. Anyway, you're right, and I'll make more of an effort.

Comment: Perhaps, if you lack the time to give a full and detailed answer, you should delete your comment = answer. You don't get the credit for being the first to come up with it, but at least there won't be two or three answers skirting round it. It's like the elephant in the room, we all know it's there! :))

Comment: @Mari-LouA For the record, though I know it won't change anything: I am completely happy with and encourage users to use anything I suggest in the comments as a full-fledged answer. I don't *claim* ownership of any such suggestions ;)

Answer (score 5):

*[Attain](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/attain)*:

> verb (used with object)
>   1. to reach, achieve, or accomplish; gain; obtain:
>
> *Dictionary.com*

*[Obtain](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=obtain&allowed_in_frame=0)* was suggested in the OP, but it is a better choice:

> early 15c., from Middle French obtenir "acquire, obtain" (14c.), from
>   Latin obtinere "hold, hold fast, take hold of, get possession of,
>   acquire," from ob "to" (though perhaps intensive in this case; see
>   ob-) + tenere "to hold" (see tenet).
>
> *Etymonline.com*

Comment: Alternatively, acquire.

Answer (score 4):

Reclaim.

Although this is not in the literal sense claiming something which you have *never* had, in many cases it effectively means so:

'Finally I **reclaimed** the family heirloom that had been lost for years among the bric-a-brac.'

Answer (score 2):

*[Gain](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gain)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1 Obtain or secure (something wanted or desirable):
>
> *ODO*

Answer (score 1):

*[Achieve](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/achieve)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   Successfully bring about or reach (a desired objective
>   or result) by effort, skill, or courage:
>
> *ODO*

Comment: Achieve is close, but I'm looking for a word that describes a state in which: you've already earned "it" (or achieved it), but haven't been able to utilize it until now...

Comment: Of the words presented so far, I believe *obtain* is probably your **best** option.

Comment: The etymology of the word achieve emphasizes "finish". The earning is not enough. I have earned my PhD degree, but when it is awarded it will be a real achievement.

Answer (score 1):

```
the act of taking that which is rightly yours...something like secure, capture, or seize
```

### At long last he had assumed his birthright, taking responsibility and seizing power!

> **ASSUME** *verb*
>
> **2**. **Take** or begin to have (*power or responsibility*): ‘he *assumed* full responsibility for all organizational work’
>
> **2.1.** **Seize** (*power or control*): ‘the rebels *assumed* control of the capital’;
>
> *Origin*: Late Middle English: from Latin *assumere*, from *ad*- 'toward' + *sumere* 'take'. see Oxford Dictionaries [assume](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/assume)

Answer (score 0):

Redeem

> Exchange (a coupon, voucher, or trading stamp) for merchandise, a discount, or money.

This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Redeem works as in *redeem* your lottery ticket, but I never would have guessed from the title of the question, because one of the dominant definitions for [redeem](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/redeem) is to repay for past mistakes, and the definition that suggests acquire also suggests "reacquire."

Answer (score -1):

Declare.

As in the Declaration of Independence which asserted rightful possession of things previously asserted to be withheld.

Comment: *assert* is the operative word in your answer, not declare.